# SSRS - adding button to SSRS toolbar

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

is it possible to add a button to the SSRS toolbar?

Currently on the toolbar you see export, the refresh and the print button. I would like to add a button that will link to a new page.

Is this possible?

Comment: what kind of new page? another aspx page? if you mean another report page, it automatically makes a page if the select you have created is Long enough for another page. if another aspx page or whatso ever, i usually put the button outside ssrs toolbox.

Comment: The new page could be a link to any website... www.google.com for example.

Comment: Why not just add a navigation link in the report itself?

Comment: That's the second option if the first is not possible

Answer (score 2):

There is no method to add your *own* buttons to the toolbar itself. You can, however, enable the [Page Navigation buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251670.aspx) that allow the user to go back/forward or jump to a specific page.